# ActionScript AddChild to Stage from Class

Tags: php, actionscript-3, oop, class, addchild

I am trying to add an object to my main stage via the `addChild()` method. Normally, when working within the FLA itself, using `addChild(myObject)` works just fine. However, it does not work within an external AS class.

All of the other tutorials I have found showed me how to do something like this, which is not what I need:

```
var myMovieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
myMovieClip.addChild(myObject); // Works great, but not what I need
```

Could someone please show me how to add an object to my **main stage** via an external AS class.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your document class or a class that has a valid stage reference, you could use:

```
stage.addChild(myObject);
```

EDIT - Added example.

Here is an example class that extends EventDispatcher and passes a parameter of the 'stage'.

First, the class:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    public class MyClass extends EventDispatcher {

        private var _stage:Stage;

        public function MyClass(stage:Stage) {
            _stage = stage;

            var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            _stage.addChild(mc);
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage (assuming this is from a class that has reference to 'stage'):

```
var obj:MyClass = new MyClass(null, this.stage);
```

Comment: Hmm... That seems a little difficult to do, as this class already extends EventDispatcher, and I would really like to avoid having to implement it, since I would need to extend MovieClip. Any other work-arounds?

Comment: What is your class extending? What error are you getting? If an instance of your class has been added to the display list, you should be able to access stage like mentioned above...it doesn't need to be the document class.

Comment: Yes, my class extends EventDispatcher. I'm relatively new to AS3, so, what do you mean "added to the display list"?

Comment: The EventDispatcher class does not have a reference to the stage, so you'll need to pass one to it...either by setting up a public variable or a parameter in your constructor. Then, when you instantiate your class, you can pass in the stage reference.

Comment: Awesome!!! This is one of the mysteries of ActionScript I can consider conquered! Thanks for your help, Corey!

Comment: I think it would be good to add the information about passing a stage reference , directly to the answer.

Comment: @prototypical - Good suggestion. I've added an example above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try the following?

```
stage.addChild(myObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Corey's method works. You don't need to extend EventDispatcher like he did in his example.

What is important in his example is:

```
private var _stage:Stage;
public function MyClass(stage:Stage) {
_stage = stage;

var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
 _stage.addChild(mc);
}
```

Notice how he uses the _stage variable referencing it.